# Error in svmtrain, "Y and TRAINING must have the same number of rows"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm

I'm using svmtrain function to classify the images. And I'm getting an error like this.

```
Error using svmtrain (line 253)
Y and TRAINING must have the same number of rows.

Error in svm5 (line 80)
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training_Set , train_label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
```

Training_Set contains sets of images and train_lable is the class to which to identify the input image.
The complete code for the reference

```
clc
clear all

% Load Datasets

Dataset = 'D:\majorproject\image\traindata\';   
Testset  = 'D:\majorproject\image\testset\';


% we need to process the images first.
% Convert your images into grayscale
% Resize the images

width=100; height=100;
DataSet      = cell([], 1);

 for i=1:length(dir(fullfile(Dataset,'*.jpg')))

     % Training set process
     k = dir(fullfile(Dataset,'*.jpg'));
     k = {k(~[k.isdir]).name};
     for j=1:length(k)
        tempImage       = imread(horzcat(Dataset,filesep,k{j}));
        imgInfo         = imfinfo(horzcat(Dataset,filesep,k{j}));

         % Image transformation
         if strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'grayscale')
            % array of images
            DataSet{j}   = double(imresize(tempImage,[width height])); 
         else
            % array of images
            DataSet{j}   = double(imresize((tempImage),[width height])); 
         end
     end
 end
TestSet =  cell([], 1);
  for i=1:length(dir(fullfile(Testset,'*.jpg')))

     % Training set process
     k = dir(fullfile(Testset,'*.jpg'));
     k = {k(~[k.isdir]).name};
     for j=1:length(k)
        tempImage       = imread(horzcat(Testset,filesep,k{j}));
        imgInfo         = imfinfo(horzcat(Testset,filesep,k{j}));

         % Image transformation
         if strcmp(imgInfo.ColorType,'grayscale')
            % array of images
            TestSet{j}   = double(imresize(tempImage,[width height])); 
         else
            % array of images
            TestSet{j}   = double(imresize(tempImage,[width height])); 
         end
     end
  end

    % Prepare class label for first run of svm
% I have arranged labels 1 & 2 as per my convenience.

% It is always better to label your images numerically

% Note that for every image in our Dataset we need to provide one label.

% we have 10 images and we divided it into two label groups here.

    train_label               = zeros(size(10,1),1);
    train_label(1:4,1)   = 1;         % 1 = naa
    train_label(5:10,1)  = 2;         % 2 = ta


% Prepare numeric matrix for svmtrain

    Training_Set=[];
    for i=1:length(DataSet)
    b = imresize(DataSet{i},[100 100]);
    Training_Set_tmp= b(:);
    %Training_Set_tmp   = reshape(DataSet{i},1, 100*100);
    Training_Set=[Training_Set;Training_Set_tmp];
    end

    Test_Set=[];
    for j=1:length(TestSet)
    b = imresize(TestSet{j},[100 100]);
    Test_set_tmp= b(:);
    %Test_set_tmp   = reshape(TestSet{j},1, 100*100);
    Test_Set=[Test_Set;Test_set_tmp];
    end


% Perform first run of svm

SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training_Set, train_label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
Group     = svmclassify(SVMStruct, Test_Set);
```

please  guide me to overcome from this.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the Training_set? If it is a collection of PxPx3 RBG images I really don't think this is how you would want to use svmtrain. In most cases you would benefit from a dimensionality reduction using something like PCA, then the training set would be NxM, where N is the number of images, M are the reduced number of features, therefore train_label should be Nx1 or something similar.

Comment: Training_Set=[];
for i=1:length(DataSet)
    b = imresize(DataSet{i},[100 100]);
    Training_Set_tmp= b(:);
    %Training_Set_tmp   = reshape(DataSet{i},1, 100*100);
    Training_Set=[Training_Set;Training_Set_tmp]; this is how i get the training data

Comment: check if `size(Training_Set,1)` is the same as `length(train_label)`.

Comment: Can you put the code from the comment into the question to get a full example, runnable code showing the problem?

Comment: @user3859472 you must ***EDIT*** your question and add that code to it (nicely formatted please). It is useless in a comment.

Comment: @Kamtal no the size(training_set)=(250000 1) and  length(train_label)=10

Comment: @Trilarion and  sorry for posting code in comment

Comment: They should be the same, you should have label for each sample. BTW are you sure you want to classify your data with only one feature (25000x1 means you have 25000 samples and 1 feature for each)?

Comment: @Kamtal, I have only 10 images with me, and don't know why I'm getting 25000.

Comment: Do you understand what `b(:)` does? That's why.  Re-read Falimond's comment at top.

Comment: @nkjt i got that code from website, It is instead using reshape function; And reshape function is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently bumped into this similar problem and after hours of checking, here is the problem I found:

```
% we have 10 images and we divided it into two label groups here.

train_label               = zeros(size(10,1),1);
train_label(1:4,1)   = 1;         % 1 = naa
train_label(5:10,1)  = 2;         % 2 = ta
```

Where I have only 499 images, while instead, I set my size to 500 (Accidentally deleted 1), and thus resulting in the exact same error as above. You did not provide your data set here so maybe you can consider checking it again.